# Help me to stop saying 'Man up!'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I often utter the phrase 'Man up', or I talk about 'taking it like a man' or earning 'man points' (that last one, not so much, but I hear it still). I don't want to keep doing this, for obvious reasons; It's a bad habit, but I find myself saying it anyway.

Is there a better way of getting across that I'm 'manning up' or I expect someone else to 'man up'? Could I replace 'man' in those phrases with some other word, X and say something like 'Taking it like a(n) X'? Or should I just use a different phrase?

Comment: Could whoever decided to downvote explain? I'm open to all ideas on this.

Comment: Oh, well, you can always imitate the PC feminists and alternate between **Man up!** and **Woman up!**, or the PC egalitarians and say **Person up!**, or a reasonable speaker and say **Grow up!** I think that **adult** or **grown-up** are two reasonable substitutes for **man** in those cases, even though they may not sound good in every context. Orwell would say that using such clichés simply prevents you from thinking or relieves you from having to think about what you're saying in such a case.

Comment: How about [put on your big boy pants](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/what-does-put-ones-big-boy-girl-pants-on-mean)?

Comment: If you want to continue in a sexist, risque vein, you could say *grow a pair*. Let's not.

Comment: @bib, I'd rather not.

Comment: Feel happy to say "Man up" frequently, and not "Man down!"

Comment: Last year’s movie “Zombieland” even showcased the provocative tagline “Nut up or shut up.” [On Language: The Meaning of ‘Man Up’ http://www.nytimes.com/2010/09/05/magazine/05FOB-onlanguage-t.html?_r=0]

Comment: **Buck up**, but apparently it's Brit spoken English;"spoken used for telling someone to try harder" http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/buck-up

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Since *buck up* derives from *buck* 'male deer', we still run into the same problem.

Comment: Re: "Help me to stop saying 'Man up!'?" My advice is simply to clam up.

Comment: Simply tell several of your friends that you will pay them $10 every time they here you use the phrase.

Answer (score 10):

"Man up" is one of those phrases that can be intended to mean so many different things.  Sometimes there is an intention to refer to a 'male' stereotype, sometimes there isn't.  It sounds like you are looking for the latter.  Here are some possibilities to start you off...

- Get/grow a spine.
- Stand up for yourself.
- Assert yourself.

etc.

Comment: "Get up, stand up. Stand up for your rights."

Comment: That's what I'm after. From now on I'll try to use these instead.

Comment: Now I think about it, 'Pull your socks up' would be a good phrase as well.

Comment: Pull yourself together!

Answer (score 7):

The concept is **take responsibility**, so why not say it.

**Supplement**

In light of comment, consider *[steel yourself](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steel)*

> to ​force yourself to get ​ready to do something ​unpleasant or ​difficult:
>   [+ to infinitive] She steeled herself to ​jump out of the ​plane.

*Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

Comment: The concept I am usually trying to express is more along the lines of, "I realize that you are scared but dig down deep and find a way to move beyond that." It's a bit too wordy to use as a cliché, no?

Answer (score 5):

**[Buck up](http://sgtbrandi.com/?page_id=2260)**. A term used to make Troops bear their pain (Military speak).

Answer (score 4):

**Suck it up**.

> To put up with something; to deal with something, such as pain or misfortune, without complaining. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck_it_up))

Still perhaps not a great line for polite society, but it does avoid the gender issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is very nearly as obnoxious, and it only works for one phrase, but a good drop-in replacement for "man up" might be "**step up**", which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/step%20up) as "to come forward (*stepped up* to claim responsibility) : to succeed in meeting a challenge".

Comment: If you wanted to go the other way with it and be _more_ obnoxious, consider "cowboy up".  Just hearing it makes me want to jump out of windows.

Comment: On the other hand, and for unclear reasons, I find the concept of earning "cowboy points" delightful.

Answer (score 1):

[Brace up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brace+up)

**brace up**: to summon up one's courage; become resolute

[Grit your teeth and bear it (or get it done)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grit)

**grit one's teeth**: Summon up one's strength to face unpleasantness or overcome a difficulty

Answer (score 0):

"Man up" isn't really in my lexicon, so I'm not sure what you're looking for. 
But, if you're looking for something semi-snappy that means "take responsibility", you might try [***pull your own weight***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pull+one's+weight).

[***Bite the bullet***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+the+bullet) might replace "take it like a man".

Answer (score -1):

Are you strictly looking for vernacular? If you don't mind using more proper diction, try ***adjure***

> to charge, bind, or command earnestly and solemnly, often under oath
>   or the threat of a penalty.

That's quite similar to how you said

""I realize that you are scared but dig down deep and find a way to move beyond that.""

Comment: I'm looking for something that fits in well with everyday speech.