# What is the meaning of "on steroids"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I see this phrase coming after animal names: "A badger is basically a weasel on steroids—you wouldn’t want to upset one".

So what is its meaning?

Comment: www.oxforddictionaries.com www.dictionary.com, which are best of what I know, didn't give me any results

Comment: @RegDwigнt - If someone had only looked up [_steroids_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=steroids&ls=a), instead of the idiom [_on steroids_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=on+steroids&ls=a), the answer would have been more elusive. (That said, had the O.P. [mentioned such a search](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), I'll bet he would have been cut some slack – it works for [Yoichi](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74773)). It might be worth mentioning [ell.se]; perhaps the O.P. would want to check out that community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an allusion to steroid use by bodybuilders (in combination with exercise) causing vastly increased muscle mass over a non-steroid using average person.

It is used to mean 'a bigger (and sometimes other superlatives like tougher/stronger/meaner) version of'.